# CSS text-align property

Tags: css, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <style type="text/css">
            .name {
                font-size: 18px;
                margin-top: 1px;
                text-align: right;
            }

            .contactInfo {
                font-size: 12px;
                margin-top: 1px;
                text-align: left;
            }
        </style>
        <TITLE>Joe Sixpack</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <div id="name">
            <span class="name">Joe Sixpack</span>
        </div>

        <div id="contactInfo">
            <span class="contactInfo">
                123 Electric Ave, Mudflap, NS 12345 &#8226; (888) 555-1212 &#8226; <A HREF="mailto:Joe@Sixpack.com">Joe@Sixpack.com</A>
            </span>
        </div>

        <HR>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

The problem is that I would like the name class to be aligned to the right but it is not happening.  Both the name and the address are on the left.  Why is that and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the style on the name div, not the name span:

```
#name {
    font-size:18px;
    margin-top:1px;
    text-align:right;
}
```

Also, you might not want to have divs and spans with the same name.

Comment: thanks.  i thought also that divs and spans should be named differently but was lazy to change.  but can you tell me any specific reasons why?

Comment: Add `div { outline: 1px dashed blue } span { outline: 1px dashed green }` to see the width of these elements. Elements displayed as block (the default of `div`) will occupy the whole width of their parent so you can align their content at your will. But elements displayed as inline are the size of their content: you can't move something when there's no room for that (because `text-align` property doesn't *move* an element around, it aligns its *content*.)

Comment: use distinct names for classes and ids just to make it easier to keep track of, and avoid css clashes between .name and #name (though I get . and # wrong even with different names!)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tip, @FelipeAls -- it works great for debugging but I don't want it have it on my final page.  so basically keep it uncommented only when i need to debug it, correct?

Comment: Yes, these are rules only meant for debugging, quite the same as Firebug or Inspector when you hover an HTML node. In real use, http://outlinenone.com/ :)

Answer (score 1):

You can align text only inside block-level elements. Rewrite you CSS to be like that:

```
#name {
     font-size:18px;
     margin-top:1px;
     text-align:right;
}

#contactInfo {
     font-size:12px;
     margin-top:1px;
     text-align:left;
}
```